# App, webserver and Json

Tags: php, objective-c, swift, webserver

i have a web server that accept post request with a string like

```
value1=1&value2=2
```

now i'm writing an app that connect to that web server and make a post request to it. my post request is sent as a dictionary object

```
request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
request.HTTPBody = NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(params, options: nil, error: &error)
request.addValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
```

the web server won't read the request cause it's an object and it just read that string form.
Is it better to send the string as the server require, or it's safer to change the web server code to receive an object, to have better security performance?

Comment: you can convert dictionary to string like this 
>NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",params];

Answer (score 0):

You cannot say that in general. It depends on the complexity of the sent object graph. If it is only key-value pairs without any "subobjects" I would prefer leaving the server as is.

If it is more complex, you can use JSON in the body. (Change the MIME type in this case. Actually you are saying that you send URL encoded, but you don't. Of course this shouldn't work.) We did this at Objective-Cloud, but added support for different MIME types as well, since it depends on the data transmitted.

Please note that using `NSJSONSerializer` you can only send dictionaries et al. If you have instance objects of custom classes you have to convert them to the supported classes.